# Oracle tables partition related

Tags: oracle, update, relational-theory, partitioning

Here is my doubt. Is it possible to apply a partition to one table depending in the partitions values of another one?

Why I am asking?
I have one table where information headers are persisted, and other table where information details are stored.
As you can imagine, the second one is much bigger than the first one. The one containing headers, has an automatic partition by date, so I guess it would be desirable to partition the one with the details in order to perform queries.
Here the example:

> HEADER_TABLE
>  ID    DATE
>   -----------------------------
>  1   10/10/2010
>  2   10/10/2010 Partition 1
>  3   10/10/2010
>   -----------------------------
>  4   11/10/2010
>  5   11/10/2010 Partition 2
>   -----------------------------
>
> DETAIL_TABLE
>  ID  HEADER_FK 
>   -----------------------------
>  01     1
>  02     1
>  03     2      Partition 1
>  04     2
>  05     3
>  06     3
>   -----------------------------
>  07     4
>  08     4      Partition 2
>  09     5
>  10     5
>   -----------------------------

One way I think this could be done, is adding the date field to the details table, and to partition it in the same way than the header one, but the thing is that altering the details table in production and updating the rows (hundred millons) could be a problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **partition by reference** option 
Example :

```
create table trans (
  trans_id     number not null,
  res_id        number not null,
  trans_date  date not null,
  amt           number,
  constraint fk_trans_01
    foreign key (res_id)
    references res
)
partition by reference
   (fk_trans_01);
```

**Some restricions :**

- Parent table Primary Key and Unique constraints used for  reference
  partitioning must be enabled and non-deferrable.
- Child table “partitioning constraints” must be enabled and 
  non-deferrable
- All child table columns used in “partitioning constraints” must  be
  defined as NOT NULL.
  *This is required to assure that every child row maps to exactly one  parent row.*
- Child tables created using reference partitioning can never  be
  disassociated from their parents without being dropped. – *There is no
  ALTER TABLE command to convert a reference  partitioned table into a
  non-reference partitioned table.*
- As with other tables referenced via foreign key constraints, 
  parent tables cannot be dropped until all foreign key  constraints
  referencing them are removed.  *– In the case of reference
  partitioning, this means all descendent  tables must first be
  dropped, since the partitioning constraints on  the child tables
  cannot be disabled or dropped.*

**NOTE:**

- Reference Partitioning has strong advantages and strong limitations,
  so its use requires careful planning.

  **Reference Partitioning should not simply be used wherever possible.**
- Use of Reference Partitioning appears best suited for very large
  tables  and related tables, whose contents share the same life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

if you have at least oracle 11g you could try use Reference Partitioning which is based on foreign keys.
Please look at http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_11g_new_reference_partitioning.htm

Comment: We have recently upgraded from 10 to 11g and I did´t know that feature. Thanks for the information.